# Communication between popup.js and content-script.js throws 'The message port closed before a response was received' in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

`popup.html`

```
<button id="go">Go</button>
<script src="assets/js/popup.js"></script>
```

`popup.js`

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {go: true}, (response) => {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log('fine');
    } else {
      // This will print the mentioned error in the console
      console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }
  });
});
```

`content-script.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // It returns the object correctly // {go: true}
  console.log(request);
  if(request.go) {
    // This causes the error.
    // When I remove this line, `fine` will be printed in the console from the `if` in the `popup.js` file above.
    const go = await chrome.storage.local.get('something');
    console.log(go);
  }
});
```

And I have nothing in my `background.js`.

The issue is that it returns the error: `The message port closed before a response was received` when clicking on the start button.

I have added `return true` and `sendResponse({status: true})` either, but didn't work!

Why do these happen and how to fix them?

Comment: What does your manifest.json look like?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the content-script is being injected correctly, as shown by the [chrome extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/). If you're injecting statically, make sure your manifest.json looks like this

> ```
> "content_scripts": [
>    {
>      "matches": ["https://*.nytimes.com/*"],
>      "css": ["my-styles.css"],
>      "js": ["content-script.js"]
>    }
>  ],
> ```

if that does not work, then the problem might be with the async function you're calling in the content-script. To use it asynchronously, a `return true` can be added in the listener.

Doing so, you can remove the `async` from the function and use

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(`request: ${request.go}`);
    if(request.go) {
      chrome.storage.local.get('something')
        .then(go => console.log(go))
    }
    return true;
});
```

With this code, the problem `The message port closed before a response was received` is solved, but another one pops up -- `A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`. This error happens because no response was sent in channel, and you have to add a sendResponse to solve it, like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(`request: ${request.go}`);
    if(request.go) {
      chrome.storage.local.get('something')
        .then(go => console.log(go))
    }
    sendResponse('hello from content-script')
    return true;
});
```

Another solution with the async code:
you could wrap the code in a async function, as in:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(`request: ${request.go}`);
    if(request.go) {
      getSomething();
    }
    sendResponse('hello from content-script');
    return true;
});

async function getSomething() {
  const go = await chrome.storage.local.get('something');
  console.log(go);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @LucasMorita. And what if I have an await call inside the `onMessage.addListener`?

Comment: @kodfire maybe you could try using (async () => { await... }) inside de addListener

Comment: Thank you @LucasMorita. I've already found that, however, it is not the correct use of await. It won't await for that because when the process reaches to the async point, it won't wait for what's inside and go to the next lines...